# I am getting Cannot find an SPSite that contains the following...Error

Tags: powershell, spsite

I have a PowerShell script below:

```
    Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell

    function Get-DocInventory([string]$siteUrl) {

    $web = Get-SPWeb "http://contoso.com/sites/Test10"

    foreach ($list in $web.Lists) {

    if($excludeLists -notcontains $list.Title){

    foreach ($item in $list.Items) {

    foreach($version in $item.Versions){



    $personField = $item.Fields.GetField("Author");

    $authorObject = $personField.GetFieldValue($item["Author"]);

    $authorName = $authorObject.LookupValue;



    $userField = $version.Fields.GetField("Editor");

    $editorObject = $userField.GetFieldValue($version["Editor"]);

    $editorName = $editorObject.LookupValue;



    $localOffset = +5;

    $modified = $version["Modified"] -as [datetime];

    if($modified.IsDaylightSavingTime()){$localOffset += 1;}

    $modifiedLocal = $modified.addHours(-$localOffset);



    $data = @{

    "Version" = $version.VersionLabel

    "List Name" = $list.Title

    "Created By" = $authorName

    "Created Date" = $item["Created"]

    "Modified By" = $editorName

    "Modified Date" = ($modifiedLocal -as
    [datetime]).DateTime

    "Item Name" = $item.Name

    }

    New-Object PSObject -Property $data | Select "List Name", "Item Name",
    "Version", "Created By", "Created Date", "Modified By", "Modified Date"

    }

    }

    $web.Dispose();

    }

    }

    }
Get-DocInventory | Expport-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path C:\TestOutput.csv
```

My problem is that when I run the script I get an error

> "Cannot find an SPSite object that contains the following Id or Url:
>   `http://contoso.com/sites/Test10`".

It doesn't make sense because when I use a different Url like `http://contoso/sites/Departments/FRP` the script works.

I have tried these variations:

- `$web = Get-SPWebApplication "http://contoso.com/sites/Test10"`
- `$web = Get-SPSite "http://contoso.com/sites/Test10"`
- `$web = Get-SPWeb "http://contoso.com/sites/Test10"`

But I still get the same error mentioned previously. Can someone tell me what is wrong with the script?

Comment: Are you sure the urls are working

Comment: http://contoso.com/sites/Test10 is a SPSite, not a SPWeb, http://contoso/sites/Departments/FRP is a SPWeb

Comment: Yes the Urls are working. In regards to what you mentioned Eric, if that was an SPSite then it should have worked if I used Get-SPSite which is in one of my variations right?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that http://contoso.com/sites/Test10 is a site collection. You'd need to do something like this (untested, from memory):

```
function Get-DocInventory([string]$siteUrl) {
  $site = Get-SPSite $siteUrl
  $web = $site.RootWeb

  foreach ($list in $web.Lists) {
...
```

Comment: My question is, how can the script point to http://contoso.com/sites/Test10? In other words how will I know which site, site collection, web app does it point to if I'm not specifying a Url? Please advise.

Comment: You have to be specific in what you want to pass into your function. If you want it to be a web and you are passing in a site, then you need logic to account for it.

Comment: I do understand that but in your previous statement you mentioned that the Url was an SPSite and not an SPWeb. When I used Get-SPSite it still returned the same error is what I am getting at. Was that what you were referring to?

Answer (score 0):

/sites/test10  is both an SPSite and a SPWeb but not a WebApplication.

```
 $site =get-spsite http://contesso.com/sites/test10
  $web = $site.rootweb
  .........code here
  $site.dispose()
```

If get-spsite does not work in powershell but the url is  successful for you in the browser it will be a permissions issue

Comment: I did what you recommended and I am still getting the same error. As for permissions I have Farm Admin and should pose no problems.